# JqueryUI Slider, slide div with increments

Tags: jquery-ui, uislider

i want to use the jqueryUI slider (slide to increments) and have it slider a div for it.

I have found this: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/making-a-content-slider-with-jquery-ui/

But I want the same thing but with increments. Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

In the options, just set max to something smaller so that the scrolling has larger jumps

```
$("#myslider").slider({max: 5});
```

This would, for example, make it such that there are only 6 increments to scrolling.

I would suggest either setting the value procedurally (for dynamic content) or experimenting with the value (for static content) so that each increment shows something specific (i.e., it doesn't scroll to a point between two images.)

It may also be easier just to map each slider value to some distinct thing you would like to show.  This would be similar to the jQuery UI demo that controls tabs with a slider (http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#tabs).  You could easily make this mapping procedurally as well.